# Java 8: How to parse expiration date of debit card?

Tags: java, java-8, jodatime, java-time

It is really easy to parse expiration date of debit/credit card with Joda time:

```
org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMyy").withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("UTC"));
org.joda.time.DateTime jodaDateTime = dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime("0216");
System.out.println(jodaDateTime);
```

Out: `2016-02-01T00:00:00.000Z`

I tried to do the same but with Java Time API:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter formatter = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMyy").withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
java.time.LocalDate localDate = java.time.LocalDate.parse("0216", formatter);
System.out.println(localDate);
```

Output:

> Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate
>   from TemporalAccessor: {MonthOfYear=2, Year=2016},ISO,UTC of type
>   java.time.format.Parsed   at
>   java.time.LocalDate.from(LocalDate.java:368)  at
>   java.time.format.Parsed.query(Parsed.java:226)    at
>   java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
>     ... 30 more

Where I made a mistake and how to resolve it?

Comment: It seems like a local date cant be as broad a field as you have wanted.  Local requires a day.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) represents date that is composed of a year, a month and a day. You can't make a `LocalDate` if you don't have those three fields defined. In this case, you are parsing a month and a year, but there is no day. As such, you can't parse it in a `LocalDate`.

If the day is irrelevant, you could parse it into a [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) object:

> `YearMonth` is an immutable date-time object that represents the combination of a year and month.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMyy").withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.parse("0216", formatter);
    System.out.println(yearMonth); // prints "2016-02"
}
```

You could then transform this `YearMonth` into a `LocalDate` by adjusting it to the first day of the month for example:

```
LocalDate localDate = yearMonth.atDay(1);
```

Comment: Way to go - although in the case of a credit card it would probably be `LocalDate expiry = yearMonth.atEndOfMonth();`.

Comment: @assylias True but the OP's working example also evaluates to the first of the month.

Comment: @Tunaki, or: Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMyy").parse("1016");
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

Comment: @user471011 Yes but this uses the old Calendar / Date classes. You shouldn't use those now with Java 8 (except to operate with system that don't support Java Time).

Comment: @Tunaki, you are right, with Joda time I had one common method like parse(String date, String pattern) and I didn't care about pattern (date format). With java 8 I need to introduce logic "analysis pattern and parse date in some specific way" it is a bit painfully :(

Comment: The `.withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))` is not needed.

Comment: @JodaStephen, If I need to support 2 different kinds of Patterns ("MMyy" and "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") It means that with Java 8 I need to implement 2 different ways for parsing incoming dates?

Comment: @user471011 Not necessarily. You could use `DateTimeFormatter.parseBest`, parsing to a `YearMonth` or a `LocalDateTime`

Comment: @user471011 those two patterns have nothing in common, so best to treat them separately

Comment: @JodaStephen, could you please review my final solution?

Comment: @user471011 You shouldn't update your question with the final code. It makes the existing answers obsolete. If you want your code reviewed, you should post it on CodeReview instead. I've edited your post to remove that part.

Comment: If zone is still required, it is better to use enum:
`.withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)`